# How can I make Tkinter in python to do every code in certain amount of time?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code that supposes to do somthing every 4 hours but when I use time.sleep(14400) my GUI crashed. 
How can I make a certain code run every 4 hours using tkinter?
Thanks

Comment: [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)

Comment: after is using recursive style(as I understood), how can I use it to delay the program by 4 hours?

Comment: `after` isn't recursive, it's only task is to place things on the event queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Tkinter, the proper way to run something in the future is with the `after` method.

```
# N.B. 4 hours times 60 minutes in an hour times 60 seconds
# in a minute times 1000 milliseconds in a second
root.after(4*60*60*1000, myCode)
```

If you want something to run every four hours, you can either schedule them all at once if you know it should stop at a predetermined time, or have the job re-schedule itself after it has finished running if you want it to run forever.

Here's an example of a function that runs every 4 hours by rescheduling itself once it has completed.

```
def every4hours(self):

    <do whatever work you want here>

    self.after(4*60*60*1000, self.every4hours)
```

Comment: How Do I call the function every4hours? Calling it like this every4hours() gives me TypeError: every4hours() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: This example assumes `every4hours` is a method of a class. You are free to change the parameters and call it with any arguments that you want. Don't copy the code, learn the pattern that the code illustrates and apply it to your own code.

Comment: So how will the after method will work without the self before it?

Comment: @user3341603: yes, of course. `after` doesn't care. Of course, you have to give some sort of reference; self if you're calling from within a class, or `root` or `parent` or `some_widget` if not. `after` is a method common to all objects that inherit from a Tkinter widget.